# Android check is valid UUID

Tags: android, uuid

Is there a way that I can check if a string is a valid UUID?

In my situation, I have list of files and some of them have file names that are UUIDs generated by `UUID.randomUUID().toString()`, the rest of them are just normal `.jpg` files.

I know that by using `UUID.fromString(filename)` and catch `IllegalArgumentException` thrown I would be able to check if `filename` is a properly formatted UUID. But this seems to be very expensive considering that the file list would have plenty of files. Is there a way where I can check without having exceptions being thrown?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use a regexp: `[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12}`

Something like:

```
if(!Pattern.matches("[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12}", filename)) { 
    /* this is not a valid uuid */ 
}
```